# Multi-Label Image Classification using KNN

Tags: classification

I'm not quite sure how I should go about creating a multi-label image KNN classifier using python as a lot of the literature I have read does not explicitly explain this methodology. Specifically, I am not sure how I would be able to potentially yield multiple labels per image using the KNN classifier architecture. Any insight would be greatly appreciated! (new to coding by the way)

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried google searching? There are many results that come up for "multi-label k nearest neighbor image classification". Here are the first couple of papers to get you started:

http://proceedings.mlr.press/v25/chiang12/chiang12.pdf
http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.86.9501&rep=rep1&type=pdf